# Are there still plans to implement transparency (RGBA) in Ubuntu's theme?

Tags: themes, gtk

A while back there was a lot of talk about Canonical implementing subtle transparency in GTK for Ambiance and Radiance themes - Is this no longer on the agenda? Was there a hold up?

Comment: We're after feature freeze for 11.10, switch to gtk3 seems done. I'm starting a bounty, hoping for some **refreshed** answers that would answer this question according to current development status.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with implementing rgba currently is lying with the applications that run on the gtk+ library. However, with the switch to gtk+ 3 it is likely that Ubuntu will inherit this feature as a default option.

I'm sorry I don't have a link to hand, but the feature was not dropped, just hindered.

**EDIT:** [Here](http://live.gnome.org/GTK%2B/3.0/Roadmap) is a link that indicates the possibility of rgba as a feature of gtk3 (which Ubuntu uses as of 11.10).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's, at most, a back-burner issue. There are no blueprints from the Natty Narwhal Ubuntu Developer Summit. The last UDS I've found about it discussed at was for Maverick ([blueprint here](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/dx-m-gtk-enhancements)), in which it was dropped from the beta and listed as "POSTPONED" with no mention of which release it was postponed until.

Comment: That is because it's going to be pretty much built in in gtk+ 3. At least that is the plan, so no need for ubuntu to rush and implement a duplication of the feature.

Comment: Will they use it in the Radiance and Ambiance themes, though?

Comment: @Lightbreeze: I'm not sure what you're asking.